# Deployed webApp on tomcat macOS return 404

Tags: java, macos, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I'm trying to deploy my fullstack webApp to tomcatServer. Backend part is springBoot app and frontend part is react app. I built that using mvn clean package. I configured my pom file, so maven always runs npm i, npm run build and then it copies all files to webapps backend directory and create war file.

When I have installed the tomcat on the windows, everything works correctly. I have deployed the webApp.war to the tomcat and I can access to my webapp using localhost:8080/webApp.

I tried the same on the mashine with macOS, but localhost:8080/webApp does not work. There is shown whitescreen and all needed files return 404 code to the console.

Do you have some ideas, what is needed to be configured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually stopping the server(tomcat), again setting it to automatic and re-running the application?

Comment: Yes, sure... But right now I got new information. I tried to rename webApp.war to ROOT.war and run only localhost:8080 and everything works. Do you have some idea how to configure that?

Comment: @TatkoSmollko seems like the server is listening to ROOT.war, hence unable to detect webApp.war. Try the above process after naming it to webApp.war, then re-run it. Also its just a lucky guess as you haven't provided much information.